# Is there a way to get these parameters count and value?

Tags: javascript, parameters, callback, arguments, currying

```
function a(fun) {

}
a(function(a, b, c) {
  return a + b + c;
});
```

How can i access fun arguments and their count inside function a?

Comment: You can get the number of declared parameters. You cannot access any arguments, they only exist when you are calling the function - and you decide how and with which values to call it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bergi. That is what I was looking for.